# Why is this simple service not returning anything?

Tags: ros, rospy, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am new to ROS and have a little problem regarding services.
Right now I am sending a request to the server, triggering the **handle_speech** function.
In this function I subscribe to the **pocketsphinx recognizer/output** node.
When I return an integer value from here, the client receives it and shows it to me.

But when I return a value from the **speechCB** callback function, the client shows nothing.
What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit: Now it is working, but this code is not my best coding ;)**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('kmr01')

from kmr01.srv import *
import rospy

from std_msgs.msg import String

command = 0

def handle_speech(req):
  print "handling speech input"
  rospy.Subscriber('recognizer/output', String, speechCb)

  r = rospy.Rate(10.0)
  while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    r.sleep()
    print "sleeping"
    if command != 0:
      return RecognizeSpeechResponse(command)

def speechCb(msg):
  global command
  print "speechCB"

  if msg.data.find("forward") > -1:    
    command = 2  

  elif msg.data.find("stop") > -1 or msg.data.find("halt") > -1:          
    command = 1    

  print "nothing recognized"    
  command = 99    
     

def recognize_speech_server():
  rospy.init_node('recognize_speech_server')
  s = rospy.Service('recognize_speech', RecognizeSpeech, handle_speech)
  print "Ears wide open ..."
  rospy.spin()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  recognize_speech_server()
```

Regards
Max

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12400/why-is-this-simple-service-not-returning-anything-?/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2011-12-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

But, you're never returning a value from the service callback now? The subscribe callback function is completely unrelated to the service callback function.

If you want the service to return a value received on the topic, you have to let the topic CB store the value in some shared variable. As your service function already has a wait loop, you could poll this value there to see if it's been set. You probably want to have some global boolean also to make sure the value has been updated since the service was called (unless returning an old value is fine).

Don't know if I'd call this solution a good design, though...

---

Originally posted by [raahlb](https://answers.ros.org/users/966/raahlb/) with karma: 317 on 2011-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2011-12-19**:
I know that it is not a good design, but I put basically the service client tutorial and the voice_cmd_vel.py pocketsphinx tutorial together. I aso don't know python really well. Actually, my service should only listen for one command and then stop again.

**Comment by [raahlb](https://answers.ros.org/users/966/raahlb/) on 2011-12-19**:
BTW, by definition a topic callback can never return a value. Also you probably won't want to start a new subscription for each call to the service. Save the handle somewhere and each call check if it's set. If not, start the subscription, otherwise do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is your definition of RecognizedSpeech.srv? I presume it probably wants to return an integer, and not a string....

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-12-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2011-12-19**:
Yes, it wants to return an integer. When I use this "RecognizeSpeechResponse(1)", the client receives an integer.